# Porque PUT Request borra los datos?

Tags: spring, https, postman

Tengo una api con spring con las dos tablas con una relacion muchos a muchos:

```
public Planta() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "belongs_to",
    joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="planta_id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="sensor_id")}
)
private List<Sensor> sensores;

public Sensor() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;  

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="sensores",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Planta> plantas;
```

Hasta aqui todo bien pero cuando intento hacer un PUT con Postman, lo hago para asociar cada sensor con su planta, me borra (de la tabla intermedia) planta_id y sensor_id y luego añade los que le paso por parametro.

La api se esta ejecutando en eclipse y cuando ejecuto el request me aparece esto en la consola de eclipse:

> Hibernate: delete from belongs_to where planta_id=?
>
> Hibernate: insert into belongs_to (planta_id, sensor_id) values (?, ?)

El PUT request de POSTMAN es asi:

> http://localhost:8084/api/plantas/1/sensores

Con el body de tipo text:

> http://localhost:8084/api/sensors/1

Y con el header:

> Content-type -> text/uri-list

Alguna ayuda?
Gracias!

Comment: Podrias compartir el codigo del Controlador que maneja la PUT request?

Comment: Hola, no tengo codigo hecho en el controlador que maneja eso. Lo hago directamente en el PostaMan. Gracias!

Comment: Te comento, de manera inherente PUT request sobre un RestResource de Spring Boot hace exactamente eso, elimina el recurso y lo crea con los datos modificados que has pasado por parámetro. Si lo que quieres es modificar una propiedad de un recurso lo que debes hacer es utilizar una petición de tipo PATCH. Saludos y suerte :P.